# Cost of OS disk storage for DS-Series/GS-Series VM's

Tags: azure

I came across this [article](http://www.aidanfinn.com/?p=19094) that says OS Disks for DS-Series/GS-Series (DS/GS) VM's have by default the same fixed monthly cost and SSD performance that data disks belonging to a premium storage account do. It suggests there's a way to use a standard storage account for your OS disk while using Premium Storage for your data disks, but I don't see any obvious way to do this.

Is this actually the way it works, and if so, can somebody please let me know what the best way of setting this up is?

I tried attaching a premium storage account to a plain old D-series VM after the VM was already provisioned, but the storage account is greyed-out and says that its not supported; although, this could be because my VM is in the North-Central region where premium storage accounts can't be created, so I'm not entirely sure.

Also, there weren't any options that I noticed for configuring the OS disk with standard storage when creating a DS1 VM. The only thing I've noticed since creating this VM is the ability to change the vhd location of the OS disk, and am wondering if this is how to do it.

I should add that I've been working out of the preview portal.

Comment: Alright, dumb question. Give me a chance to look at it more closely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to Neil's answer: When you provision your DS- or GS-series VMs, you choose which storage account to use (standard storage is always an option). Same thing when adding a data disk - you get to choose the storage account, which dictates whether standard or premium storage is used.

Further: Regarding billing: You are correct in that Premium storage disks are billed at a fixed rate, depending on size chosen. This differes from Standard storage, where you are only billed for amount of disk actually consumed.

Answer (score 1):

DS and GS series VMs are available only in regions with Premium Storage. You can use Standard Storage for either or both OS or Data Disks with these VMs. You can't use Premium Storage disks with VM series except DS and GS.